# Parsing versioned JSON

Tags: c#, json, oop, design-patterns, deserialization

I have objects represented by two different Jsons:

JSON v1:

```
{
 "names":[{"name":John},{"name":Eve}],
 "version": 1
}
```

JSON v2:

```
{
  "names":[{"name":"John", "age":22},{"name":"Eve", "age":35}],
  "version": 2
}
```

Now I have class which can parse the first version of Json:

```
[JsonObject("Class")]
public class PeopleEntity
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
}

public class People
{
  public List<PeopleEntity> names{ get; set; }
  public string version{ get; set; }

}
```

And this is how it is parsed:

```
  result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(json_data, new     JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

Now, the problem is, that the request for parsing the second version of JSON came. What would be the best solution to handle this?

I have an idea to make list of interfaces (because of the attribute name, which is always there) and make multiple implementations of it, one for each version.

Comment: Well, that's certainly a question of the used json implementation. The answer is easy if you roll your own, but that's probably crazy. So which JSON library do you use? Would you be able/willing to change? Many libraries offer to deserialize a string to a dictionary. Then you can inspect the dictionary, look at `version` and choose the corresponding DTO class which can then be hydrated from the dictionary.

Comment: @mnemosyn I used Newtonsoft library. I can't change the incomming json. I know the version of the json before parsing it (It is in the name of the file).

Comment: If you know the version beforehand, what's the problem? Just serialize to the correct DTO class. It's easier to have two classes than to meddle with arcane logic during (de-)serialization. Keep the serialization simple and do the translation later, that's low coupling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for interfaces to solve this.

If you want to deserialize both versions of JSON into the same type you could add a nullable age property to `PersonEntity` like this:

```
[JsonObject("Class")]
public class PeopleEntity {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? age { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the `?` following the `int` type which means that property can be null. Using Json.NET, if you deserialize v1 JSON into this class the `name` will be populated as expected and the `age` will remain null.

Alternatively, since you know which version of JSON is being deserialized up front, you could have a different type for each version. Use you're existing `PeopleEntity` type for v1 and create a derived class that adds an `age` property for v2.